# How to access Elastic Beanstalk env var in springboot application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a springboot/Tomcat server running on Elastic Beanstalk. We want to use the Env vars set in beanstalk in our springboot code. Currently we have something like

```
Private string getvar = System.getenv("ENV_VAR");
//and have also tried
Private string getvar = System.getProperty("ENV_VAR");
```

Locally this works just fine. When it's on aws, it can't find the variables. We have them set in our EB Instance -> Configuration -> Software -> Environment Variables:

```
Key = ENV_VAR     
Value = valueWeExpect
```

and I confirmed they are set via cloudShell.

**Does anyone know if we are missing a dependency or referencing the variables incorrectly? Is there anything we have to add?**

Comment: @smac2020 What are you talking about? There is no modifications happening, only value lookups.

Comment: What you are doing looks exactly correct.

Comment: We are trying to read the value of the env var that has been set under Beanstalk -> Env -> Configuration -> Software -> Env Vars

Comment: You can use the AWS SDK for Java V2 to get values, See this Javadoc - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/elasticbeanstalk/ElasticBeanstalkClient.html#describeConfigurationOptions-software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.DescribeConfigurationOptionsRequest-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my via

```
@Autowired
private Environment _env;

_env.getProperty("ENV_VAR")
```

Environment is `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`